# How does the Android system automatically change the screen orientation?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-source

Till now, I only find the source code for user to set the orientation in Android source code. Can anyone tell me where is the source code that the system use to automatically change the screen orientation?

Comment: what are you exactly want to do? Please ask in details.

Comment: Do you want to lock or adapt to the orientation??

Comment: I just want to do some system level instrumentation to log when the screen orientation changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WindowManagerService.java`, method `public boolean updateRotationUncheckedLocked(boolean inTransaction);` do the rotation.